# 3 arrays to 1 IEnumerable<test>

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have this:

```
 public class test
 {
     int foo;
     int foo2;
     string foo3;
 }

 int[] foo = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
 int[] foo2 = new int[] { 4, 5, 6 };
 string[] foo3 = new string[] { "a", "b", "c" };
```

How can I turn those 3 arrays to IEnumberable of test?

TIA

/Lasse

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the .NET 4.0 `Enumerable.Zip` extension method:

```
foo.Zip(foo2, (first, second) => new { first, second })
    .Zip(foo3, (left, right) => new test
    {
        foo = left.first, 
        foo2 = left.second, 
        foo3 = right
    });
```

Or write a method that does this:

```
public static IEnumerable<test> FooCombiner(int[] foo,
    int[] foo2, string[] foo3)
{
    for (int index = 0; index < foo.Length; index++)
    {
        yield return new test
        {
            foo = foo[index], 
            foo2 = foo2[index], 
            foo3 = foo3[index]
        };
    }
}
```

The last example is the most readable IMO.

Comment: using yield also makes it quite elegant. So it's definitive the latter that's most readable.

Comment: Also prefer the last example. In production code, it should probably be secured with some code verifying that all arrays are of the same length.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static IEnumerable<test> Test(int[] foo, int[] foo2, string[] foo3)
{
    // do some length checking
    for (int i = 0; i < foo.Length; i++)
    {
        yield return new test()
        {
            foo = foo[i],
            foo2 = foo2[i],
            foo3 = foo3[i]
        };
    }
}
```

You can add some length checking or make it with foreach, but i think idea is shown

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code if you don't like loops:

```
List<test> result = Enumerable.Range(0, foo.Length).Select(i => new test() { foo = foo[i], foo2 = foo2[i], foo3 = foo3[i] }).ToList();
```

Comment: I get like 3 of index 0, somehow all values are of [0]

Comment: You did something wrong, try to copy-paste exact code. Maybe forgot 'i' in index: foo2[i]

Comment: Was MVC Html.Textbox helper that was messing with me and only showing first one when in loop. Problem solved